# filegetcsv causing infinite loop

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Trying to use `filegetcsv` to parse a CSV file and do stuff with it, using the following code found all over the Internet, including the [PHP function definition](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) page:

```
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        print_r($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

But the code gives me an infinite loop of warnings on the `$data =` line:

```
PHP Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...
```

1. I know the file I'm opening is a valid file, because if I add a dummy character to the file name I get a different error and no loop.
2. The file is in a folder with full permissions.
3. I'm not using a CSV generated by an Excel on Mac ([there's a quirky error there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321064/csvs-without-quotes-not-working-with-fgetcsv))
4. PHP version 5.1.6, so there should be no problem with the function
5. I know the file's not too big, or malformed, because I kept shrinking the original file to see if that was a problem and finally just created a custom file in Notepad with nothing more than two lines like:

   Value1A,Value1B,Value1C,Value1D

Still looping and giving no data. Here's the full code I'm working with now (using a variable that's greater than the number of lines so I can prove that it would loop infinitely without actually giving my server an infinite loop)

```
if ($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/test-csv-file.csv', 'r') !== FALSE) {
    while ((($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) && ($row < 10)) {
        print_r($data);
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

So I really have two questions.

1) What could I possibly be overlooking that is causing this loop? I'm half-convinced it's something really "face-palm" simple...

2) Why is the recommended code for this function something that can cause an infinite loop if the file exists but there is some unknown problem? I would have thought the purpose of the `!== FALSE` and so forth would be to prevent that kind of stuff.

Comment: And that's an exact copy/paste of your code, you didn't retype it by hand?

Comment: I copied and pasted around some comments I had, so I just copied and pasted the whole thing and removed the comments in case my original had an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no question about what's going on here: the file is not opened successfully. That's why `$handle` is a `bool` instead of a resource (`var_dump($handle)` to confirm this yourself).

`fgetcsv` then returns `null` (not `false`!) because there's an error, and your test doesn't pick this up because you are testing with `!== false`. As the documentation states:

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on
>   other errors, including end of file.

I agree that returning `null` and `false` for different error conditions is not ideal, and furthermore that it's against the precedent established by lots of other functions, but that's just how it is (and things [could be](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) [worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702744/cheking-and-error-on-a-php-function/2702909#2702909)). As things stand, you can simply change the test to

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ","))
```

and it will work correctly in both cases.

**Update:**

You are the victim of assignment inside an `if` condition:

```
if ($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/test-csv-file.csv', 'r') !== FALSE)
```

should have been

```
// wrap the assignment to $handle inside parens!
if (($handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp/test-csv-file.csv', 'r')) !== FALSE)
```

I 'm sure you understand what went wrong here. This is the reason why I choose to *never, ever, make assignments inside conditionals*. I don't care that it's possible. I don't care that it's shorter. I don't even care that sometimes it's quite less "elegant" to write the loop if the assignment is taken out. If you value your sanity, consider doing the same.

Comment: OK, so basically I need to stop looking for obscure fgetscv problems and investigate why my fopen isn't doing what I'm expecting? (I'm successfully using fopen on other scripts so I can go down that route)

Comment: @joshuahedlund: Yes. `file_exists` and `is_readable` might help. However, you should have already received an `E_WARNING` if `fopen` failed. Is `error_reporting` on (it should be)?

Comment: @joshuahedlund: On the other hand, it turns out that you simply have wrong syntax inside your first `if`. See my update.

Comment: The parentheses update did it! Somewhere in my customizing from my copy and paste I must have lost it. Embarrasingly obvious now that I see it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
            $row = 1;
            if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['csv-file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
                $data = fgetcsv($handle , 1000 , ",");
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {


                    $num = count($data);
                    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
                    $row++;
                    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
```

Try given Code Snippet once,because as i have noticed you are missing some important things in your code.